# Cannot add Dependencies to Spring project which converted to maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I created a java project -> converted it into a maven project. what i supposed to do with this project is try some Spring core codes.

Following what i getting when i try to add dependencies.

[image]

can anyone help me to open a project?
Thanks.

Comment: Your `pom.xml` is malformed. `dependency` must be under `dependencies`

Comment: Do not violate the convention over configuration and remove `<sourceDirecrtory>src</sourceDirectory>` and follow the convention which mean source code (production) in `src/main/java` and unit test code in `src/test/java` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency need surrounded by dependencies

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   ...
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```